# How to grab values from one csv file and plug them into specific places in separate csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm going to explain what I'm trying to do here. Then share what I have tried so far...

I have 2 csv files....

CSV File1 (ContractorDomain.csv) looks something like this...

```
"SamAccountName","FirstName","LastName"
"2v2390s"       ,"Jr.,John" ,"Doe"
"4gsi2f2"       ,"Peter"    ,"Pan"
"asdfds9"       ,"Leo"      ,"Turtle"
"2fsa02f"       ,"Chuck"    ,"Findly"
"4gas5a3"       ,"Stan"     ,"Garcia"
"1asfd32"       ,"Linsey"   ,"Silver"
```

I am only interested in getting the column `SamAccountName`

Now for csv file2 (employeeList.csv) looks something like this...

```
"DomainNamesFromAD"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"ContractorDomain"
"ContractorDomain"
"ContractorDomain"
"ContractorDomain"
"ContractorDomain"
"ContractorDomain"
```

The end goal is to make csv file2 (employeeList.csv) look like this...

```
"DomainNamesFromAD","SamAccountNameFromAD"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","4gsi2f2"
"ContractorDomain","asdfds9"
"ContractorDomain","2fsa02f"
"ContractorDomain","4gas5a3"
"ContractorDomain","1asfd32"
```

## What I have tried so far...

I feel like I am almost there, but i need a little help. Here is the code I have...

```
$ContractorSamAccountNames = Import-Csv ContractorDomain.csv | 
    Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName

$csvFormatContractorSamAccountNames = $ContractorSamAccountNames | Select-Object @{Name='SamAccountName';Expression={$_}}
```

Now if I export `$csvFormatContractorSamAccountNames` to a csv file, it shows the correct column and values. So I know I'm getting the values. Now here is where I try to plug them into file 2...

```
Import-Csv employeeList.csv | 
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='SamAccountNameFromAD';e={
    if ($_.DomainNamesFromAD -eq "ContractorDomain") {"Found"}}} |
    Export-Csv "employeeListTemp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am selecting the correct row in csv file2 (employeeList.csv). However, I need to somehow replace `"Found"` with the values in `$csvFormatContractorSamAccountNames` (using a for loop maybe?).

I've also tried this:

```
$num = 0
Import-Csv employeeList.csv | 
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='SamAccountNameFromAD';e={
    if ($_.DomainNamesFromAD -eq "ContractorDomain") 
    {
        $ContractorSamAccountNames[$num]
        $num++
    }}} |
    Export-Csv "employeeListTemp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But this only fills in the first value of the array `$ContractorSamAccountNames`. In other words, the file looks like the following...

```
"DomainNamesFromAD","SamAccountNameFromAD"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"PermDomain"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
```

I'm not sure why $num++ does not increment. Anyone who can help with this is much appreciated. I've been at this for 5 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

```
$ContractorSamAccountNames = Import-Csv ContractorDomain.csv | 
    Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName

$script:numOfContractorSamAccountNames = 0
Import-Csv employeeList.csv | 
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='SamAccountNameFromAD';e={
    if ($_.DomainNamesFromAD -eq "ContractorDomain") {$ContractorSamAccountNames[$script:numOfContractorSamAccountNames];$script:numOfContractorSamAccountNames++}}} |
Export-Csv "employeeListTemp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to join two csv files when having the domain name in the file name of the import file(s).  I did a test with two import files ...

CSV File1 (ContractorDomain.csv)  like yours

CSV File2 (PermDomain.csv)

```
"SamAccountName","FirstName","LastName"
"JCarter"       ,"Jimmy"    ,"Carter"
"RReagan"       ,"Ronald"   ,"Reagan"
"GBush"         ,"George"   ,"Bush"
"BClinton"      ,"Bill"     ,"Clinton"
"GWBush"        ,"George W.","Bush"
"BObama"        ,"Barack"   ,"Obama"
```

The script ..

```
$Local:SourceFilesPathes = @("C:\temp\stackoverflow.com_34245941\ContractorDomain.csv", "C:\temp\stackoverflow.com_34245941\PermDomain.csv")

$Local:OutFilePath       = "C:\temp\stackoverflow.com_34245941\employeeList.csv"
$Local:OutFileObjectList = @()

$SourceFilesPathes | ForEach-Object {
    $Current_SourceFilePath = $_

    if ( (Test-Path -Path $Current_SourceFilePath -PathType leaf) ) {
        $Local:Current_DomainName         = (Get-Item  -Path $Current_SourceFilePath).BaseName   # Domain name from file name
        $Local:Current_SourceFileContent  = Import-Csv -Path $Current_SourceFilePath -Delimiter ","

        $Current_SourceFileContent.ForEach({
            $Local:Current_OutFileEntryObject = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSObject
            $Current_OutFileEntryObject | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "DomainNamesFromAD"    -Value $Current_DomainName
            $Current_OutFileEntryObject | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "SamAccountNameFromAD" -Value ($_.SamAccountName)
            $OutFileObjectList += $Current_OutFileEntryObject
        })
    }
}

# Select-Object to order the properties inside CSV.  From left "DomainNamesFromAD", "SamAccountNameFromAD"
# Sort-Object to order the entries
$OutFileObjectList | Select-Object -Property DomainNamesFromAD, SamAccountNameFromAD | Sort-Object -Property DomainNamesFromAD, SamAccountNameFromAD | Export-Csv -Path $OutFilePath -Delimiter "," -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

The out file ...

```
"DomainNamesFromAD","SamAccountNameFromAD"
"ContractorDomain","1asfd32"
"ContractorDomain","2fsa02f"
"ContractorDomain","2v2390s"
"ContractorDomain","4gas5a3"
"ContractorDomain","4gsi2f2"
"ContractorDomain","asdfds9"
"PermDomain","BClinton"
"PermDomain","BObama"
"PermDomain","GBush"
"PermDomain","GWBush"
"PermDomain","JCarter"
"PermDomain","RReagan"
```

Comment: At the end of your code you have `$OutFileObjectList | Select-Object -Property DomainNamesFromAD, SamAccountName | Sort-Object -Property DomainNamesFromAD, SamAccountName | Export-Csv -Path $OutFilePath -Delimiter "," -Force -NoTypeInformation`. can't use -delimiter `","`. Some of the names have a `,` in them and this would break the iterations.

Comment: Also, They want the column name to be `"SamAccountNameFromAd"`, because this will be used later to compare with different reports.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Comma would work fine with `Export-CSV` as the data will be quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution on your way ...

```
$ContractorSamAccountNames = Import-Csv  "C:\temp\stackoverflow.com_34245941\ContractorDomain.csv" | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName
$i = 0

@(Import-Csv "C:\temp\stackoverflow.com_34245941\employeeList.csv" -Delimiter ",").ForEach({
    if ($_.DomainNamesFromAD -eq "ContractorDomain") {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "SamAccountNameFromAD" -Value ($ContractorSamAccountNames[$i++].SamAccountName) -Force
    }
    $_
})) | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\stackoverflow.com_34245941\employeeList.csv" -Delimiter "," -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

I tried your example starting with "$num = 0".  The point is that $num is still 0 after running the script.  In other words:  There is no way without a foreach loop.

Another problem is that you need exactly the same numbers of entries for each domain in both files.

Comment: This is almost the same as the answer I just gave. The only issue I see here (unless i'm reading it wrong), is the off by 1 error. You have `$ContractorSamAccountNames[$i++]` in the expression, which will pull `$array[1]` first instead of `$array[0]` first. Right?

Comment: Btw, the way to do the foreach loop is `$script:i = 0`. then to call the value within the expression would be `$ContractorSamAccountNames[$script:i]; $script:i++`. Also, I agree with you on exact number of entries, however I can say for certain they will always be exact. This is a very large script I'm working on and I always copy files locally before manipulating the data.

Comment: Worng!  $i++ means count up 1 _after_ using.   The way solve the problem is interesting.

Comment: Ah I see, my mistake :) I forgot about that when I was studying c++ a while back.